# How to declare variable inside xsl:perform-sort

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a sophiscated sorting like this:

```
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$nodes">
        <xsl:sort select="if (p:isPreform(.) and not(p:getPreformPart(., $nodes))) then 1 else 0"/>
        <xsl:sort select="p:getTargetPart(., $nodes)/../@pos"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if (sort:isGroupElement(p:getTargetPart(., $nodes), $subsectionId)) then
                                sort:getGroupId(p:getTargetPart(., $nodes), $subsectionId)
                          else
                                p:getTargetPart(., $nodes)/@name"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if (sort:isGroupElement(p:getTargetPart(., $nodes), $subsectionId)) then 0 else 1"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(p:getTargetPart(., $nodes)/@number, '[А-Я]+$','')"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if (p:isPreform(.)) then 1 else 0"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@number"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
```

You can see repeating constructions inside. How I can refactor this? Specification not allow declare variables inside  if that were the case - same fragment may look like:

```
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$nodes">
        <xsl:variable name="isPreform" select="p:isPreform(.)" as="xs:boolean"/>
        <xsl:variable name="target" select="p:getTargetPart(., $nodes)" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="isGrouped" select="sort:isGroupElement($target, $subsectionId)" as="xs:boolean"/>

        <xsl:sort select="if ($isPreform and not(p:getPreformPart(., $nodes))) then 1 else 0"/>
        <xsl:sort select="$target/../@pos"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if ($isGrouped) then sort:getGroupId($target, $subsectionId) else $target/@name"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if ($isGrouped) then 0 else 1"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace($target/@number, '[А-Я]+$','')"/>
        <xsl:sort select="if ($isPreform) then 1 else 0"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@number"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
```

Maybe I miss something? And I can sort this by another way?

In advance thanks! Andrey.

Comment: I don't have a solution to the variable problem but I see you have some sort keys computed as `1`/`0` where you seem to sort based on a boolean condition. You could shorten those expressions as booleans are perfectably sortable, https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#op.boolean, so `select="if ($isGrouped) then 0 else 1"` could be written as `select="not($isGrouped))"` and similarly for the other expressions.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I work around by create a temporary structure, save calculated unique id for each node and attributes inside for-each, and then inside perform-sort i just get this attributes from there and do the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am stating the obvious, but it is much more readable to do the following instead of seeking a compromise by adding variables inside `<xsl:perform-sort>` . One reason this was not allowed by the creators of XSLT 2.0 probably was to discourage complexity -- therefore no sequence constructor was allowed as the body of `<xsl:perform-sort>` -- the same way it isn't allowed inside the body of `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

**I would use (and encourage everyone to use) something like this**:

```
   <xsl:perform-sort select="$nodes">
        <xsl:sort select="f:key1(., $nodes)"/>
        <xsl:sort select="f:key2(., $nodes)"/>
        <xsl:sort select="f:key3(., $nodes, $subsectionId)"/>
        <xsl:sort select="f:key4(., $nodes, $subsectionId)""/>
        <xsl:sort select="f:key5(., $nodes))"/>
        <xsl:sort select="f:key6(.)"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@number"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
```

Here I would have meaningful names for the functions `f:keyN()` so that it would be naturally understandable what the rules for the sorting are.

Any repeated expression is a candidate to be implemented by a separate function and called by other functions when necessary. Thus redundancy can and will be avoided -- this is a major programming principle called *abstraction*.

Comment: We had a request to allow xsl:variable before xsl:sort for XSLT 3.0, and spent a little time on it, but it did get surprisingly complicated (the variable has to be computed once for each item in the input sequence: should it still be in scope when producing the output sequence, and if so, should it retain its original value?) We decided that the requirement could be met better using memo functions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Exactly!  If implemented this would have been the ugliest feature ever in XSLT.